# Default setting for "Floating Notifications" on android

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there a way to enable the "floating notification" flag by default on Android 11?

[image]

We have an app that features video calls. On most devices the notifications work as intended, but we notice that on some devices this flag is disabled by default. The device will receive the notification and will display it in the notification drawer, but there is no popup. We dont want to ask our users to go and enable this, so we really need a way to have this enabled by default.

Comment: "we really need a way to have this enabled by default" -- I will be somewhat surprised if that is possible. However, at the same time, I do not how where this item is that you have highlighted. How are you getting to this screen, and on what device is this screen from?

Comment: That isn't a setting in Android.  It's probably the setting in some particular dialer app you use.  So no, there's no way to set that globally on all Android devices because it doesn't exist on all android devices.  As for setting it on those where it does exist-  probably not, although you'd need to figure out what app it is and see if they have an API available to know for sure.

Comment: This option is visible on android 11 samsung devices, for all apps

Comment: Floating notifications option exist for Xiaomi devices too, starting from Android 10. And Iam really wondering how to enable it by default for my app, when using Android 13, my notification no longer appear as floating.